# Remove unnecessary spacing in responsive website

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, mobile-website

I am just learning how to code and I can't figure out how to remove the unnecessary spacing on the top & bottom of the form field & button (as shown by the red stars). There's no margin or padding there.

My website looks great on desktop but when I change it to mobile, there's unnecessary spacing. Thanks in advance for your help.

CSS code:

```
/* Margins */
.my-1 {
margin: 1rem 0;
}

.my-2 {
 margin: 1.5rem 0;
}

.my-3 {
 margin: 2rem 0;
}

.my-4 {
 margin: 3rem 0;
}

.my-5 {
 margin: 4rem 0;
 }
```

Comment: Could you also post a snippet of the HTML that corresponds to the screenshot and CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code for the space is my-5 in the div `<div class="waitlist-form my-5">`. Here you are telling the margin on the y-axis to be 5

an easy way to troubleshoot is to use inspect your html with your browser tools and view the box model. As you can see in the screen shot it is telling you that the top and bottom margin are set to 64px.

[image]

bootstrap has helper classes for various screen sizes so you can change the margin depending on the screensize.

```
<div class="waitlist-form my-5 my-sm-1">
```

have a look at using breakpoints in Bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/

Comment: Ah, thank you! I'll be making the browser tool my new best friend so I can inspect the html code. I'll check out the doc too. Thanks!

Comment: Great to hear! If you found my answer helpful please can you accept as the answer.

Comment: also being able to troubleshoot code is a great skill to have, enjoy!

Comment: To add to this answer, it's a good idea to familiarize yourself with these helper classes Bootstrap has. They're named very intuitively (in my opinion) and they're very handy.

Answer (score 0):

You need use a @mediaquery(min-width: your specific broke size){

}

and low padding-top or padding-bottom of the elements that you want more togheter.

Comment: Hi Joel, thanks for answering my question! I tried setting padding-top & padding-bottom to 0 but it didn't do anything.